# Ansible-Playbook to install Kubernetes cluster gives GPG error

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-inventory

For my virtualisation class, our lab assignment at the moment is to create a kubernete's cluster with 3 VM's / Nodes. I have a fourth machine where i installed ansible on that sends all correct commands to the nodes.

We have a guide on how to do this and its been fun learning about it but currently i've been stuck for quite a bit sadly and i'm looking for some help. It seems to be related to OpenPGP key verification when i read the error. I looked up what this is and tried disabling it (from some StackOverflow asnwer) but i get the same error when executing the command to create the cluster.

**I'll show you a small part of the guide, the inventory + playbook.yaml file and the error message:**

> Head over to the Ansible playbook directory on your local machine (you
> should have copied it from the USB in the last step). You should be
> able to see a automated-install.yaml file in this directory. This is
> the Ansible playbook which contains the references to the various
> roles that need to be executed on the nodes. common role: This is the
> role used to set the node's hostname (based on the inventory file) and
> install the required Kubernetes packages (kubelet, kubeadm and cri-o).
>
> The Ansible playbook requires the community_general Ansible collection
> to be present on the system. In order to install this, just execute
> ansible-galaxy collection install community.general in the
> ansible_playbook directory. Executing the Ansible playbook - and thus
> creating the Kubernetes cluster - is as easy as executing the
> ansibleplaybook command with our inventory file and the playbook file
> as arguments. In this case, your command should look something like
> this: ansible-playbook -i inventory.yaml automated-install.yaml . Once
> executed, you should be greeted by a screen like in the screenshot
> below.

```
    inventory.yaml file: 
master:
  hosts:
    node-01:
      ansible_host: 10.0.6.75
      ansible_user: robot
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ./ssh_key

worker:
  hosts:
    node-02:
      ansible_host: 10.0.6.76
      ansible_user: robot
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ./ssh_key
    node-03:
      ansible_host: 10.0.6.77
      ansible_user: robot
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ./ssh_key
```

automated-install.yaml file:

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  roles:
    - common
- hosts: master
  become: true
  roles:
    - name: kubernetes-master
      vars:
        disable_gpg_check: true (added this line but didn't fix error) 
- hosts: worker
  become: true
  roles:
    - name: kubernetes-worker
      vars:
        disable_gpg_check: true (added this line but didn't fix error)
```

ls of current dir: automated-install.yaml  group_vars  inventory.yaml  roles  ssh_key

full output, including error message of my command to create k8 cluster.

```
PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************ok: [node-03]
ok: [node-02]
ok: [node-01]

TASK [common : Set the node's hostname] ********************************************************************************ok: [node-02]
ok: [node-03]
ok: [node-01]

TASK [common : Install Kubernetes required packages] *******************************************************************fatal: [node-02]: FAILED! => {"action": "install", "changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rpm-ostree install --allow-inactive --idempotent --unchanged-exit-77 kubelet-1.27.3 kubeadm-1.27.3 cri-o-1.26.1 libselinux-python3", "msg": "non-zero return code", "packages": ["kubelet-1.27.3", "kubeadm-1.27.3", "cri-o-1.26.1", "libselinux-python3"], "rc": 1, "stderr": "error: Updating rpm-md repo 'kubernetes': cannot update repo 'kubernetes': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Error during parsing OpenPGP packets: Parsing an OpenPGP packet:\n  Failed to parse Signature Packet\n      because: Signature appears to be created by a non-conformant OpenPGP implementation, see <https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351>.\n      because: Malformed MPI: leading bit is not set: expected bit 8 to be set in       10 (2)\n", "stderr_lines": ["error: Updating rpm-md repo 'kubernetes': cannot update repo 'kubernetes': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Error during parsing OpenPGP packets: Parsing an OpenPGP packet:", "  Failed to parse Signature Packet", "      because: Signature appears to be created by a non-conformant OpenPGP implementation, see <https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351>.", "      because: Malformed MPI: leading bit is not set: expected bit 8 to be set in       10 (2)"], "stdout": "Checking out tree 926547c...done\nEnabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora kubernetes updates-archive\nUpdating metadata for 'kubernetes'...done\n", "stdout_lines": ["Checking out tree 926547c...done", "Enabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora kubernetes updates-archive", "Updating metadata for 'kubernetes'...done"]}
fatal: [node-03]: FAILED! => {"action": "install", "changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rpm-ostree install --allow-inactive --idempotent --unchanged-exit-77 kubelet-1.27.3 kubeadm-1.27.3 cri-o-1.26.1 libselinux-python3", "msg": "non-zero return code", "packages": ["kubelet-1.27.3", "kubeadm-1.27.3", "cri-o-1.26.1", "libselinux-python3"], "rc": 1, "stderr": "error: Updating rpm-md repo 'kubernetes': cannot update repo 'kubernetes': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Error during parsing OpenPGP packets: Parsing an OpenPGP packet:\n  Failed to parse Signature Packet\n      because: Signature appears to be created by a non-conformant OpenPGP implementation, see <https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351>.\n      because: Malformed MPI: leading bit is not set: expected bit 8 to be set in  1001001 (49)\n", "stderr_lines": ["error: Updating rpm-md repo 'kubernetes': cannot update repo 'kubernetes': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Error during parsing OpenPGP packets: Parsing an OpenPGP packet:", "  Failed to parse Signature Packet", "      because: Signature appears to be created by a non-conformant OpenPGP implementation, see <https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351>.", "      because: Malformed MPI: leading bit is not set: expected bit 8 to be set in  1001001 (49)"], "stdout": "Checking out tree 926547c...done\nEnabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora kubernetes updates-archive\nUpdating metadata for 'kubernetes'...done\n", "stdout_lines": ["Checking out tree 926547c...done", "Enabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora kubernetes updates-archive", "Updating metadata for 'kubernetes'...done"]}
fatal: [node-01]: FAILED! => {"action": "install", "changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rpm-ostree install --allow-inactive --idempotent --unchanged-exit-77 kubelet-1.27.3 kubeadm-1.27.3 cri-o-1.26.1 libselinux-python3", "msg": "non-zero return code", "packages": ["kubelet-1.27.3", "kubeadm-1.27.3", "cri-o-1.26.1", "libselinux-python3"], "rc": 1, "stderr": "error: Updating rpm-md repo 'kubernetes': cannot update repo 'kubernetes': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Error during parsing OpenPGP packets: Parsing an OpenPGP packet:\n  Failed to parse Signature Packet\n      because: Signature appears to be created by a non-conformant OpenPGP implementation, see <https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351>.\n      because: Malformed MPI: leading bit is not set: expected bit 8 to be set in   101011 (2b)\n", "stderr_lines": ["error: Updating rpm-md repo 'kubernetes': cannot update repo 'kubernetes': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: Error during parsing OpenPGP packets: Parsing an OpenPGP packet:", "  Failed to parse Signature Packet", "      because: Signature appears to be created by a non-conformant OpenPGP implementation, see <https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/issues/2351>.", "      because: Malformed MPI: leading bit is not set: expected bit 8 to be set in   101011 (2b)"], "stdout": "Checking out tree 926547c...done\nEnabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora kubernetes updates-archive\nUpdating metadata for 'kubernetes'...done\n", "stdout_lines": ["Checking out tree 926547c...done", "Enabled rpm-md repositories: fedora-cisco-openh264 updates fedora kubernetes updates-archive", "Updating metadata for 'kubernetes'...done"]}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************node-01                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
node-02                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
node-03                    : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I tried some things (googling the error, looking at some yt videos regarding ansible but i haven't been able to fix this. Any help is highly appreciated! <33